# Update UITableView when UIScrollView content changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have 2 ViewControllers, each of which includes a scrollview (that shows several graphs) and a tableview.
I'd like to update the tableview content based on the current graph displayed in the scrollview.

The scrollview is managed by a separate class "GraphScrollView", where the property currentIndex stores the current graph displayed.

The problem is that I don't know how to inform the viewController that currentIndex is changed so that it can send the reloadData method to update the tableview.
I was thinking to post a notification in the GraphScrollView class and add an Observer in the 2 viewControllers but in this case the 2 ViewControllers would be both informed while I want to inform only the viewController of the currently active view (because the two VC should be independent and also because the 2 viewControllers could have a different number of graphs and consequently the currentIndex could be a wrong value for one of the two VC).

Thanks,
Corrado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you could set and remove the view controllers as observers when the "active view" changes.

You could also create a delegate protocol and switch which view controller was the delegate but I actually find that to be more work than notifications for no particular gain.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question how do you change `currentIndex` in your scroll views. But you can always implement UIScrollViewDelegate in your view controller to get an update when scroll has ended:

```
...
@implementation ViewController 
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   ...
   self.graphScrollView.delegate = self;
   ... 

}

...
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   if (self.graphScrollView.currentIndex == ???) {
       [self.tableView reloadData];
   }
}
...
```